# How to change the OnClick color of the StackView in widget

Tags: android, android-widget, stackview

I am building an android widget with the a StackView in it. Using pending intent I open my activity when the StackItem is clicked. 
Whenever the StackView Item is clicked(i.e. Pressed), the background of the StackItem changes to default blue color.
**IS THERE ANY WAY TO CHANGE THIS DEFAULT BLUE COLOR TO A CUSTOM COLOUR.
Please Help..!**
Thank you!

Comment: see this http://www.broculos.net/2011/12/android-101-how-to-create-stackview.html

Comment: Thankx nitesh; but that link does not answer my question.